# How do I make sure I've got the job?

Tags: interviewing, internship

I have had a skype interview for an internship abroad which will start in March (that's my choice, they are/were looking for someone urgently). Anyway I got an email from them. It's not stated but clear that I've got the job. Like she has written these lines: the interview was great and the result is even greater. Please note that you can extend the contract, check out the benefit package, etc. I send them a thank you email and told them I'm going to contact them again in February for the visa procedures(I responded 4 days later). But I didn't get a response back and now kinda worried that they may find someone else and forget about me. How do I follow up with them in order to secure the job?

Comment: "It's not stated but clear that I've got the job." - That does not sound clear to me. Even if they like you now, anything can happen between now and March.

Comment: By that I meant they didn't explicitly state that I've been selected. But they said the result is great, the contract is extendable and sent the benefit package. So I sent them a "thank you for selecting me as your new management trainee" email. No response back, it's been almost a week

Comment: They might be waiting for you to agree to their offer. After confirming that they are offering you the position also ask them for something in writing which mentions compensation, benefits, and start and end date of the contract period.

Comment: Depending on the country were the job is located, I would not wait until February for visa procedures for travel in March. Even if the normal processing time is fast enough, there can be delays if e.g. there is a paperwork problem. I suggest getting all the paperwork in order and then filing as early as permitted.

Comment: Do you have a signed contract? This is your only sure way of "having the job". And you might even need it for the visa procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the responses I've contacted one of the employees there. He said I should ask for the contract. What should I write in the email?

Comment: Can you call them?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I follow up with them in order to secure the job?

If your offer letter is not clear, I would suggest you *call them as soon as possible and clear up any uncertainty*.  A phone call or Skype call is best in a case like this because obviously written communication may not be this companies strong point or it could possibly be a language issue.

**Short answer**:  Pick up the phone and call them or use Skype but **talk** to them.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, I would say it's pretty much clear that you've got the job.

Now coming to the response, you shouldn't have waited for 4 days to send a reply. Normally, when a person takes time to respond to an email, especially regarding a job offer, it can create a doubt in the employer's mind. It might seem to the employer that you are undecided whether to accept or decline the offer, or you have other offers in hand and that you are taking time to choose one of them.

I think, you still have a chance. I would simply send them a friendly reminder as a reply to your earlier email. I would just state that you were waiting for their response. You can also ask them the next steps without talking about the result. Their response will make things much clearer whether you have actually got the job or not. Once that is done, you can then ask for a formal letter stating your appointment.

Calling them and doing all this might look a bit rude and might seem as if you are in a hurry. Wait for it. Things will sort out themselves. And as you said, it's expensive in your case. So I would rule out this option.

On the contrary, one can also think that the person whom you were corresponding via email is actually busy and has not viewed her inbox since 4 days. We don't know. It's just a lot of if(s) and but(s) that we are talking about here.

All the best and let all of us know what the end result was.